# Como enviar los datos de un formulario a dos archivos php diferentes para realizar un update por un lado y una consulta por el otro

Tags: javascript, mysql, update

Buenas Tardes tengo el siguiente formulario:

```html
<form id="procesarActivos" method="POST"   action="updateBienes.php">
            <input type="hidden" id="Empleado" name="Empleado" value="<?=$Numero_Empleado?>">    
            <input type="hidden" id="Cantidad" name="Cantidad" value="0"/>
            <div>
                <table class="table table-striped" id="tablaAgregarArticulos">
                <thead> 
                <tr><th>ACTIVO</th></tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="contenidoActivos"></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="btnCerrarModal">Cerrar</button>
                <button type="submit" name="btnProcesarActivos" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnProcesarActivos"  disabled="disable">Procesar</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Tal cual se muestra el código envía los datos que se van generando en el form, y pasan al archivo indicado, realiza los updates que se indican en este archivo,  mi necesidad es poder enviar los mismos datos para poder cargar unas listas en una vista en pantalla.  Es decir por un lado que haga los updates y por el otro una consulta para mostrar unas listas basado en los mismo datos del form.

intente con una función script pero no hace nada...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("btnProcesarActivos").click(function(){
  $.post("updateBienes.php",$("#procesarActivos").serialize(),function(){
   alert("La informacion fue recibida por el archivo 1 ");
  });

  $.post("procesarActivos.php",$("#procesarActivos").serialize(),function(){
   alert("La informacion fue recibida por el archivo 2 ");
  });

  return false;  
 });
});
```

Gracias de antemano

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Usa funciones y clases en tus script de PHP y los vas indexando con `require` o `include` para llamar las funciones desde un archivo central y hacer las dos en el back de tu petición ajax.

Comment: No se me había ocurrido.Realizar la petición Ajax, encapsular los datos, y enviárselos a un archivo php para que este los "procese" repartiéndolos a los otros dos archivos que ya funcionan de manera separada...  Gracias deja lo intento.

Comment: Si, incluso te recomiendo que uses POO y DAO para que tus datos esten seguros.

Comment: Saludos Ivan ,  estoy programando a tres capas, manejo POO y PDO, se me ha difucultado precisamente por este detalle

Comment: PDO es tu libreria de conexión, DAO es un modelo de acceso a datos que se lleva bien con POO para generar sistemas mas seguros, puedes revisar la teoria aqui: (DAO)[http://elblogdeslacker.blogspot.com/2015/01/patron-dao-en-php-data-access-object-in.html]

Comment: el enlace me indica: Bad Request Error 400, Gracias por ofrecerme ayuda, déjame intentar lo de la petición Ajax creo que es una buena opción o alternativa.

Comment: http://elblogdeslacker.blogspot.com/2015/01/patron-dao-en-php-data-access-object-in.html listo